# Does in_array have length restriction in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**I have an array to be searched** from numerous **order_status_id**

**$order_status_id** is pulled from a mysqli_query, which is working perfect for other conditional checks (in_array)

Below is the full code -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","abc_admin","abc123!","abc_store");//database connection
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$store_name_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `value` FROM `oc_setting` WHERE `key`='config_name' AND `store_id`='0' AND `code`='config'");
$store_name_result = mysqli_fetch_array($store_name_query);
$store_name = $store_name_result['value'];

$date = date('Y-m-d');

$date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date_time_formatted = date("d M Y h:i:s A",strtotime($date_time));
$return_details = "SELECT * FROM `oc_return` WHERE `return_status_id`='1'";
if($return_data = mysqli_query($con,$return_details))
{
$count = mysqli_num_rows($return_data);
echo "<h1> $count Returns Processing</h1>";
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($return_data))
{

$return_id = $row['return_id'];
echo "Fetching Details for Return ID $return_id<br><br>";
$order_id = $row['order_id'];
$customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
$firstname = mb_convert_case($row['firstname'], MB_CASE_TITLE,"UTF-8");
$lastname = mb_convert_case($row['lastname'], MB_CASE_TITLE,"UTF-8");
$customer_name = $firstname." ".$lastname;
$email = $row['email'];
$product = $row['product'];
$comment = $row['comment'];
$return_date = $row['date_added'];
$date_added = date("d M Y",strtotime($row['date_added']));
$resolution_date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date_added. ' + 15 days'));
$resolution_date_in_format = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($return_date. ' + 15 days'));
$mobile = $row['telephone'];
$return_reason_id = $row['return_reason_id'];

$order_date = $row['date_ordered'];
$order_details = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `oc_order` WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'");
echo "Fetching Details for Order ID $order_id<br><br>";
while ($order_total = mysqli_fetch_array($order_details))
{
$total = str_replace(".0000","",$order_total['total']);
$order_status_id = $order_total['order_status_id']; 
echo "$order_status_id<br><br>";

// CONDITIONAL CHECKS


$shipped_ud = "3 || 32";
$shipped_ud_status = explode(' || ',$shipped_ud);
$ready_process = "15 || 23 || 39";
$ready_process_status = explode(' || ',$ready_process);
$other_status_ids = "1 || 7 || 11 || 13 || 21 || 22 || 24 || 25 || 26 || 27 || 28 || 29 || 30 || 31 || 33 || 34 || 35 || 36 || 37 || 38 || 40";
$other_statuses = explode(' || ', $other_status_ids);


// IF ORDER IS IN PROCESSING STATE ↓ //

if($order_status_id == '2')
{
    $cancel_comment = 'Order cancelled by Customer';
    $cancel_order = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_order` SET `order_status_id`='24' WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'");
    $cancel_order_history = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_order_history` (`order_id`,`order_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$order_id','24','1','$cancel_comment','$date_time')");
    echo "Order has been cancelled<br><br>";

    $update_return_table = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_return` SET `return_status_id`='4',`return_action_id`='4' WHERE `return_id`='$return_id'");

    $return_history_comment = "Your return request to cancel the order has been successfully processed. We are sorry to see you go away!";

    $add_return_history = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_return_history` (`return_id`, `return_status_id`, `notify`, `comment`, `date_added`) VALUES ('$return_id','4','1','$return_history_comment','$date_time')");


   //Send Email to customer if order is in processing state //
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';



try {
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "help@abcabc123.com"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "Tmob134624!";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->AddAddress("$email", "$customer_name");
  $mail->SetFrom('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', "Order Return/Cancellation Request $return_id - Order ID $order_id");
  $mail->XMailer = ' ';
  $Subject = "Order Cancellation Request | Order ID $order_id";
  $mail->Subject = "$Subject";
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically


   // Message //
$mail->Body = " \r\n";

// Body of Email trimmed 

$mail->Send();
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
}
// IF ORDER IS SHIPPED OR IN TRANSIT ↓ //
else if(in_array($order_status_id,$shipped_ud_status))

{
    $cancel_if_shipped = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_order_history` (`order_id`,`order_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$order_id','24','1','Order Shipped, Cancellation Requested by Customer','$date_time')");

    $update_return_for_shipped = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_return` SET `return_status_id`='3',`return_action_id`='4' WHERE `return_id`='$return_id'");

    //Email //
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';



try {
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "help@abcabc123.com"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "Tmob134624!";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->AddAddress("$email", "$customer_name");
  $mail->SetFrom('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', "Order Return - Order ID $order_id");
  $mail->XMailer = ' ';
  $Subject = "Return Request Update | Order ID $order_id";
  $mail->Subject = "$Subject";
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically


   // Message //
$mail->Body = " \r\n";
// Body of Email trimmed 
$mail->Send();
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}

}

// IF ORDER IS PROCESSED OR IN READY TO SHIP STATE ↓

else if(in_array($order_status_id,$ready_process_status))
{

// SEND EMAIL TO CUSTOMER

    //Email //
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';



try {
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "info@abcabc123.com"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "Tmob134624!";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('info@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->AddAddress($email, $customer_name);
  $mail->SetFrom('info@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', "Order Return Request ID $return_id - Order ID $order_id");
  $mail->XMailer = ' ';
  $Subject = "Return Request Update | Order ID $order_id";
  $mail->Subject = "$Subject";
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically


   // Message //
$mail->Body = " \r\n";

// Body of Email trimmed 

$mail->Send();
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}

// Send SMS to Processing Team

// SMS Code //

$msg = "URGENT : ".$store_name."
Order ID ".$order_id."
Customer - ".$customer_name." 
has been cancelled by Customer. Please DO NOT process this order.";

// $length= strlen($msg);

// $sms_count = ceil($length/160);

$sms_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$msg);
$cc_mobile = '12456789';
        ////////////Promotion API Key 5y6zMwrqCEOs5oGJ6xyVZg //////////////////        
        $encode= rawurlencode($msg);
        //request parameters array
        $requestParams = array(
            'channel' => '2',
            'APIKey' => 'J8yAjtZkTUqMnDy6SDQN6Q',
            'senderid' => 'ABCABC',
            'Number' => $cc_mobile,
            'Text' => $encode,
            'DCS' => '0',
            'Route' => '1',
            'Flashsms' => '0',
        );

        //merge API url and parameters
        $apiUrl = "https://login.smshub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?";
        foreach($requestParams as $key => $val){
            $apiUrl .= $key.'='.($val).'&';
        }
        $apiUrl = rtrim($apiUrl, "&");

        //API call
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$apiUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,0);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch) > 0) {
            print 'There was a cURL error: ' . $curl_error($ch);
        }

        $json = json_decode($data);
        $JobID = $json->{'JobId'};


        curl_close($ch);
        echo "Order Cancellation message sent to $cc_mobile <br><br>";

// End of SMS Code//

$cancel_if_processed = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_order_history` (`order_id`,`order_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$order_id','24','1','Customer Requested Cancellation','$date_time')");

$cancel_if_processed = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_order_history` (`order_id`,`order_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$order_id','24','1','Order Shipped, Cancellation Requested by Customer','$date_time')");

    $update_return_for_processed = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_return` SET `return_status_id`='13',`return_action_id`='4' WHERE `return_id`='$return_id'");

}

else if($order_status_id == '17')
{
   $return_processing = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_return` SET `return_status_id`='7' WHERE `return_id`='$return_id'");

echo "Return Status Updated to <strong>Processing</strong> for Return ID $return_id<br><br>";
$processing_comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"<p><i>We are sorry that you are unsatisfied with your purchase from our store.</i></p><p>Your Return Request $return_id has been received and is being looked into by our Returns Processing Team.</p><p>We request you to please read our <a href='https://www.abcabc123.com/cancellation-and-refund' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;'>Cancellation & Return Policy</a></p><p>All decisions regarding Returns shall be final & binding as per our policy.<p><p>We shall update you latest by $resolution_date regarding your return as our minimum TAT is 15 days.<p>");

$return_history = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_return_history`(`return_id`,`return_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$return_id','7','1','$processing_comment','$date_time')");

$resolution_comment = "Your return has been marked as Complete/Processed by our Returns Processing Team as the same does not meet our Cancellation and Returns policy for Refund or Replacement.";

$return_history_resolution = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_return_history`(`return_id`,`return_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$return_id','3','0','$resolution_comment','$resolution_date_in_format')");


$cancel_if_delivered = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_order_history` (`order_id`,`order_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$order_id','40','1','Order Delivered, Return Requested by Customer','$date_time')");

    $update_order_for_delivered = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_order` SET `order_status_id`='40' WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'");

    $update_return_for_delivered = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_return` SET `return_status_id`='7' WHERE `return_id`='$order_id'");



//Email Receiver//
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';


try {
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "ssl://abcabc123.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "help@abcabc123.com"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "Tmob134624!";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->AddAddress("$email", "$firstname $lastname");
  $mail->SetFrom('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('help@abcabc123.com', 'AbcAbc123');
  $mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To',"Return ID $return_id");
  $mail->XMailer = ' ';
  $mail->Subject = "Your Return Request ID $return_id is being processed";
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically  
  $mail->Body = " \r\n ";
  // Body of Email trimmed 

 $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
} 
// EMAIL SENT ↑
}

// OTHER STATUSES 

else if(in_array($order_status_id,$other_statuses))
{
    echo "Checked positive for <span style='color:red;'>Other</span><br>";
    $update_return_for_other = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `oc_return` SET `return_status_id`='3' WHERE `return_id`='$return_id'");

$return_history_for_other = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `oc_return_history`(`return_id`,`return_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$return_id','3','1','Return Invalid','$date_time')");
echo "Order not to be processed<br><br>";

}


// RETURNS UPDATED ↑
else
{
    echo "Nothing to be processed <br><br>";
}

}
}
}
?>
```

> **$update_return_for_other** mysqli_query works like charm for other checks being done before this check

My Code is processing other **in_array** checks which are small but, not this one!

Don't know what is the issue. Please help

Comment: What is `$other_status_id`? Also, if any of the previous conditions are met, this block won't be executed. Try verifying the condition directly with `var_dump(in_array($order_status_id, $other_statuses));`.

Comment: Order Status ID, is fetched from Database for Real Values and Other Status ID's are the ones to be checked. No Previous conditons are met before which is why this shall be the highlighted condition to process the check.

Comment: I see. What did the `var_dump()` call print? As far as I know this operation should be memory-bound and you will definitely not approach that limit with such a small array.

Comment: Print Result `bool(true)`

Comment: And you're certain the block isn't executing? Are those strings echo'd to the screen? If the block is not executing then you definitely have a condition evaluating to `true` before.

Comment: See the block has already checked for possibilities of `in_array` for other **order_status_id's** 

`IF()
{
//Process code if condition true
}
ELSE IF()
{
//Process code if condition true
}
ELSE IF() 
{
//Process code if condition true
}
ELSE IF(in_array($order_status_id,$other_statuses)) ↓↓↓
{
// Current Code here

}`

Comment: Else provide me a suitable code for my task.
Throw Some light on **IF OR ELSE** working!

Comment: Are *any* of those blocks executing? One of them **must** be if your in_array condition is true and it's still not executing.

Comment: @ishegg Please check my full code, I've updated the same.